# GUIText is deprecated, so what should I use instead of it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 2017.2.0f3 and when I use [`GUIText`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIText.html), it is showing "this component is part of the legacy UI system and will be removed in a future release." So what is the best alternative I should use?

Comment: This is unfortunate. I use GUIText for debug output and Canvas is overkill.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [`Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) component replaced it. It's part of the new UI system called uGUI.

Go to GameObject ---> UI ---> Text and Unity will create a Canvas with a GameObject as a child. That child GameObject will have a `Text` component. You can learn more about the new UI system [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/user-interface-ui).

Example of how to modify it from code:

```
public Text myText;

void Start()
{
    myText.text = "This is my text";
}
```

Comment: Just a note for using the new UI Framework in code. Text (or any other new UI Element) is part of UnityEngine.UI. You will have to add a using statement or use UnityEngine.UI.Text, as Unity does not automatically add it for you.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Although with Visual Studio, that's an easy fix as it will give you suggestion on what to import.

Answer (score 0):

It is now replaced with the `TextElement` class in UnityEngine.UIElements

http://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/UIElements.TextElement.html