# Unity GUIText replacement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on an Oculus project with unity.
Even though I'm trying to keep the project as clean as possible, 3 of the default scripts in the "Standard Assets" folder have the same warning:

> warning CS0618: 'UnityEngine.GUIText' is obsolete: `This component is part of the legacy UI system and will be removed in a future release.'

Those cs files declare components as the following:

```
public class SimpleActivatorMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    // An incredibly simple menu which, when given references
    // to gameobjects in the scene
    public GUIText camSwitchButton;
    ...
}
```

I want to get rid of those warnings on my project, but i don't know what class to use instead. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, your question has been answered here already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47447542/guitext-is-deprecated-so-what-should-i-use-instead-of-it. Let me know if you need more info!

Comment: It works! I don't know why I didn't found that answer... sorry