# GUIText replacement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Alright so I'm learning unity right now and I opened my game this morning and ran into this error code

```
Assets\Standard Assets\Utility\SimpleActivatorMenu.cs(11,16): error CS0619: 
'GUIText' is obsolete: 'GUIText has been removed. Use UI.Text instead.'
```

I have tried replacing `GUIText` with `UI.Text` however that lead to a different error messages of:

```
Assets\Standard Assets\Utility\SimpleActivatorMenu.cs(11,16): error CS0246:
The type or namespace name 'UI' could not be found (are you missing a using
directive or an assembly reference?)
```

or

```
Assets\Standard Assets\Utility\SimpleActivatorMenu.cs(11,16): error CS0246:
The type or namespace name 'UIText' could not be found (are you missing a using
directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: Did your using statements include UnityEngine.UI?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GUIText is deprecated, so what should I use instead of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47447542/guitext-is-deprecated-so-what-should-i-use-instead-of-it)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply replace GUIText with Text unfortunately. Check this answer out:

[GUIText is deprecated, so what should I use instead of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47447542/guitext-is-deprecated-so-what-should-i-use-instead-of-it)

Answer (score 1):

you can just replace it using [Text](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.Text.html) from UnityEngine.UI

Here's an example:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace YourNameSpace.Utility
{
    public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Text myText;

        void Start()
        {
          myText.text = "Your text here";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fallow these steps

1. adding **"using UnityEngine.UI;"** begining of .cs file
2. change all **GUIText** to **Text**.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line :

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

and then replace :

```
GUIText with Text
```